# why is this css not getting applied in my ng app?

Tags: angular, angular5

I've ng new'd up a new ng app.  I'm using the default app.component that was created.  What's the easiest way to make all the font arial in the app?  I was thinking that I could just create a css definition for the body like this to display all the font in the view as arial:

```
body
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

I haven't used css in a few months.  Is this css declaration incorrect or are there some caveats in ng for declaring css styles for a view?

Comment: What file are the styles in? For global styles you need to put it in styles.css

Answer (score 0):

your css somewhere got overwritten in your project. Apply !important tag when you want to forcefully apply your css .

```
body 
{
    font-family:arial !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
}
```